# Reorder NSSet UITableView

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsset

I have a NSSet relationship within my core data model with `routinedet` being the 1-to-many relationship

I am recalling the 'detail' view using the following which works fine and displays the data within a uitableview.

```
NSArray* array=[self.routine.routinedet allObjects];
    RoutinesDetails* det=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=det.name;
```

I am trying to add the ability to reorder and need to sort my method in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
```

I am not sure as to what I should have here to update the array and add the ability to permanently sort it. Is there a quick fix or do I need to change my core data model to include a `displayOrder` attribute and sort it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using iCloud Core Data syncing you might be able to use an `NSOrderedSet`. Otherwise, yes, you'll have to manually store the ordering, either in the Core Data model of externally.

Comment: i will be using icloud syncing eventually so I think I will put it within core data. Thank you. Was pretty much what I wanted to know